# Stream data from Heroku Postgresql to AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-redshift, apache-kafka-streams, aws-glue, heroku-postgres, heroku-api

I have this task of streaming changes made to a table in Heroku Postgresql to Redshift. I tried using examples in this article https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/stream-changes-from-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-using-amazon-kinesis-data-streams-and-aws-lambda/. But I found Heroku does not allow users to access WAL or replications as you need super user access (rds_superuser and rds_replication), and this is reserved for Heroku  only. Their reason is that it poses a security issue. This makes using Kinesis to not be an option. I added a KafKa addon to Heroku  but I am still facing issues to make this requirement work. I setup VPC access to Heroku from AWS and also Kafka certificates added to AWS to use Glue Studio for streaming from kafaka using a connector, but still no cucess yet.

Has anyone done something similar and if so how?

Comment: if you have no access to replication you may have to choose from a) move away from heroku. b) replicate the entire table each x minutes and deal with the changes using transformations in redshift or c) set up a batch job to read just the new data from postgres and write it to redshift (keeping track of id or timestamp per table)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions, option A will be a long term goal, and I do not know if option B will work due to Heroku's restrictions about replications. Option C sounds promising, can you list steps or examples where I can read from heroku postgresql to redshift using a batch job?